# python3 diagnostic line number logger

Tags: python-3.x, logging, output, diagnostics, line-numbers

I have a 600 line python 3 program that reads data every minute computes and displays output.It hangs after about an hour.  If I run it in debug mode with Pycharm it doesn't hang.So I need some form of line logger that will output each line before if executes to a text file.  When it hangs I will then be able see which line is the problem.   I don't see anything in the diagnostics docs that will do this, has anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [trace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html#module-trace) module.  A bare minimum solution would be the following on a command line.

```
python -m trace -t yourfile.py
```

You will likely want to use one or both of the filter options.

I am a bit worried about the following.  A hour is 3600 second.  Python can execute perhaps 100000 statements in a second.  That is a lot of lines.

Also, tracing slows execution by an unknown factor, so it it also prevents a hang, how long will you wait to determine this?  In fact, are you really sure that 'debug with PyCharm' prevented the hang, rather than delaying it longer than you waited?  If so, what might it be doing to prevent the hang?

Comment: Thanks Terry will try that. The program loops once every minute so I may get 36000 lines per hour and if it hangs after an hour or so shouldn't be too bad, maybe 72000 lines.The program goes for  8 hours and under pycharm it completes.  I'l give the trace 3 hours or so and if it is still working then something else is amiss.

Comment: trace worked fine with output to a tk frame , found a 'while file remove' statement was stuck , thanks

Comment: I guess it wasn't just that so I am back to tracing and now need to output trace to a file ,either to start trace  within the code and have trace output to a local file.I could delete the file every minute or so to keep the file size down